# Angular Universal pre-generated pages: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I've been trying to piece together how to pre-generate pages of an existing Angular Universal application. I'm stuck on this exception:

> The selector "app-root" did not match any elements.

I get that exception when I execute `node dist/pre-render.js /`.

Note this application works fine with `ng serve` and `npm run build:universal; npm run serve:universal`. So this isn't just as simple as forgetting to put something in `app.module`'s `declarations`.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run `npm run build:universal`
2. Run `node dist/pre-render.js /`
3. Observe the error `The selector "app-root" did not match any elements`

Here's the setup:

## `package.json` scripts section

I think this is identical to [the Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal#build-and-run-with-universal).

```
"build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
"serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
"webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

## `webpack.server.config.js`

This is also [straight out of the guide](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-webpack-configuration), except you'll notice I have an additional `entry` which produces my `pre-render.js` script from `pre-render.ts` which I show next.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        server: './server.ts',
        'pre-render': './pre-render.ts'
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
    target: 'node',
    // This makes sure we include node_modules and other third-party libraries.
    externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
        // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
            path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            {}
        )
    ]
};
```

## `pre-render.ts`

I took hints from [the guide's `server.ts` file](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-web-server) and from [a book by Philippe Martin](https://leanpub.com/angular-universal). The guide doesn't yet explain how to do this stuff, and Philippe's book's example didn't work for me.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

const args = process.argv.slice(2);
if (args.length !== 1) {
    process.stdout.write('Usage: node dist/pre-render.js <url>');
    process.exit();
}

enableProdMode();
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

renderModuleFactory(
    AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    {
        url: args[0],
        extraProviders: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
        ]
    }
).then(rendered => {
    process.stdout.write(rendered);
});
```

To be honest I have no idea what the `extraProviders` property is for, or if `provideModuleMap(...)` is the right thing to toss in there. But if I do not give it any `extraProviders` then I get this error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MODULE_MAP

So clearly that property must be important for something.

Also, I noticed that dropping in a `document` property alongside `url` and `extraProviders` has no effect, even if the `document` property is a string without any `<app-root>` elements.

Comment: With the help of folks at https://gitter.im/angular/angular I may only be missing the correct contents to place into the `document` property. They also pointed me to https://github.com/angular/universal-starter with which I'll compare my code. I should know more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

All that was missing was a `document` property containing an `<app-root></app-root>` element in the string somewhere.

It works when I pass this object as the second parameter to `renderModuleFactory`. Notice the addition of the `document` property:

```
document: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>`,
url: args[0],
extraProviders: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
]
```

Now, while this causes something to be rendered, it isn't exactly the correct thing, because we're starting with a `document` string that is different than the contents of our `index.html`.

To fix that, just do what the Angular Universal Starter does in [its `prerender.ts` file](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts):

```
const index = readFileSync(join('browser', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
  document: index,
  url: route,
  extraProviders: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
})
```

Notice how they read in the contents of the compiled `browser/index.html` file and use *that* string for the `document` property.

Comment: I will note that doing this now makes my `pre-render.ts` script similar to [the Angular Universal Starter's `pre-render.ts` script](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/prerender.ts), only worse. So I might just use theirs.

Answer (score -1):

Add below lines in your server.ts file.

```
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
 }));
```

This will help to map the module on server side.

Comment: In my case I'm not using Express to render things, but am printing the rendered output directly to console. So the `ngExpressEngine` doesn't apply. Also, I already have my `server.ts` file set up correctly and working. In my case I'm asking about my custom `pre-render.ts` file.

Comment: To elaborate a little more: what you're talking about is server-side rendering. The difference between that and prerendering is outlined here: https://github.com/angular/universal-starter#build-time-prerenderprerender-vs-server-side-renderingssr

Comment: Thank you for attempting an answer, though. And welcome to Stack Overflow!